# How to use Response in nonstatic method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
EmailContentDAL example = new EmailContentDAL();
example.Pdf(sMailBody);
```

EmailContentDAL  is a Class name.Pdf is a nonStatic method but Response in not working in pdf method

```
public void Pdf(string sMailBody)
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sMailBody.ToString()));
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc,
    Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GetPass_" + passno + ".pdf");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it not compiling? Throwing an exception at runtime? Something else?

Comment: `Response` is not some automatic global value, but a property of the Page class, that all aspx pages inherit from. As this method is in a "EmailContentDAL" class, you don't have that Response property here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that we don't see any error message, I'm just providing an advice:

Why not use the Response object as an argument to the `Pdf` method? Doing this you will not hide the `Reponse` dependency inside the `Pdf` method.

```
public void Pdf(string sMailBody, Response currentResponse)
{
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sMailBody.ToString() ));
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, 
    currentResponse.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    currentResponse.Clear();
    currentResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    currentResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; "+
                              "filename=GetPass_" + passno + ".pdf");
   currentResponse.Buffer = true;
   currentResponse.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   currentResponse.Write(pdfDoc);
   currentResponse.End();
}
```

To call the method:

```
example.Pdf(sMailBody, Response);
```

By using this approach you can easily test your method by mocking the `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.xxx` In the `Pdf` method.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

Or declare it once in the method

```
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

Then you can write `Response.xxx` as you normally would.